# How to delete files from public folder?

Tags: 7, hooks, files

I am storing some files in  public folder, programmatically I want to delete those files through the provided path. I tried using below code, but not worked.

```
function delete_public_files($arg1, $arg2){ 
  $uri = 'public://'; 
  $path= file_create_url($uri);
  $fullpath = $path.$arg1.'/'.$arg2;

  //file_unmanaged_delete($fullpath);

  $fid = db_query("SELECT fid FROM {file_managed} WHERE uri = :path", array(':path' => $fullpath))->fetchField();
  if ($fid) {
    $file = file_load($fid);
    file_delete($file);
  }
  else {
    file_unmanaged_delete($fullpath);
  }
}
```

These files are not recorded in the file_managed table and file_usage table also. So how can I delete these files. If I pass the path to `file_delete($fullpath);` It will says error that first argument should be object. So how can I achieve all these things. Thanks for any appreciation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[file_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_delete/7.x) deletes a file where it is located and its database record also.

First check file_load whether it is rendering an object file.

```
// load the file
$file = file_load('YOUR_FILE_ID');

// delete file from disk and from database
file_delete($file);
```

The `file_delete()` also takes a second argument `$force` that if set to `TRUE` will remove the file even if it's reported as in use by the `file_usage` table.

use `drupal_unlink($fullpath)` if files are not recorded in the file_managed table and file_usage table.

See [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/drupal_unlink/7.x)

Comment: Thank you for this information.I have  mentioned that Files storage record is not at all present in any table of the database.So if loop will fails, but  else loop should work rite.

Comment: @AAjayKumarReddy You should make it as answer.

Comment: @Jimmy , edited previous answer and included in that.